# Reordenar una matriz en matlab

Tags: matlab

Me gustaría reordenar una matriz de una forma concreta.
Pongamos que tengo la siguiente matriz

```
A=[1 2 0;
   3 4 0;
   0 0 0]
```

y el resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente

```
Answer=[1 0 2;
        0 0 0;
        3 0 4];
```

Si ayuda, dispongo de una matriz booleana donde los 1 representan las posiciones buscadas:

```
bool=[1 0 1;
      0 0 0;
      1 0 1]
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: Finalmente lo conseguí con la condición de que tiene que ser un vector y por tanto, es algo diferente (aunque para lo que buscaba me sirvió igualmente así que no necesito ayuda jeje), paso el código por si interesa en el siguiente comentario.

Comment: En los comentarios no se ve bien. Pon la solución en una respuesta y marcala como aceptada

Comment: Errores de novato, ya mismo arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[1 5 0; 4 9 0; 0 0 0];
bool=[1 0 1]; 
matriz=zeros(3,3);
%{ i-> filas de bool
j-> columnas de bool 
filas-> filas de a 
columnas-> columnas de a %} 
filas=1; 
for i=1:3
 columnas=0;
  for j=1:3
   if bool(1,i)==1 && bool(1,j)==1 
     columnas=columnas+1; 
     matriz(i,j)=a(filas,columnas);
      if columnas==2 % porque no puede haber 
                     % mas de 2 nodos para 
                     % una misma barra 
         filas=filas+1;
      end
   end
 end 
end
 disp(matriz)
 disp(a)
```